# Write $e^x+4=y^{(5)}+6y^{'''}-3y+2$ as a system of first-order equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write $e^x+4=y^{(5)}+6y^{'''}-3y+2$ as a system of first-order equations.

I was under the impression that usually $x$ is a function of $t$, and right now I am not sure whether I am expected to express $x$ or $y$ and its derivatives. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: By context,  $y$ would be a function of $x$, most likely.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience in this field with me.

Comment: I will try to do is that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$x_1=y$ imply $x'_1=y'=x_2$

$x_2=y'$ imply $x'_2=y''=x_3$

$x_3=y''$ imply $x'_3=y'''=x_4$

$x_4=y'''$ imply $x'_4=y^{(4)}=x_5$

$x_5=y^{(4)}$ imply $x'_5=y^{(5)}=-6y'''+3y+e^x+2$

Then

$x'_1=x_2$

$x'_2=x_3$

$x'_3=x_4$

$x'_4=x_5$

$x'_5=-6x_4+3x_1+e^x+2$